# Error of linear regression

Tags: probability, statistics, regression, least-squares

I am not sure if the title correctly captures my question(I apologize if it doesn't).

In linear regression whose matrix form is
$$Y = Xb + E$$
where $X=[X_1,X_2]$.

If the error of using only $X_1$ (i.e $ Y = X_1b+E$ ) is $x_1$, and the error of using $X_2$ (i.e $ Y=X_2b+E$) is $e_2$, what is the range the error using both columns, i.e $Y=[X_1,X_2]b + E$?

I tried to project $Y$ to $X_1$, $X_2$, and the $span\{X\}$ using Gram-Schmidt, but I think I might overcomplicate the problem and haven't got anything yet.